# Generate Odd Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am building content for a math quiz. I want to ask, "is this function even or odd?".

I would like to generate hundreds of odd functions, because I can take the product of two odd functions to generate even functions.

Is there an algorithm for building odd functions?

Comment: How about $\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$ for all function $f$?

Comment: @C.Falcon I'm not sure what that formula is supposed to generate, it is constant (and thus even) for $f(x) = x^2$ and odd for $f(x) = e^x$.

Comment: @orlp The constant function equals to $0$ is both even and odd and this what you get plugging an even function $f$ in the above formula. In fact, the above formula gives the odd part of $f$.

Comment: @C.Falcon Ah right, $0$ is both... My bad.

Comment: @C.Falcon so plug any function `f` into the algorithm you gave, and the result will be an odd function?

Comment: Yes, exactly! :-)

Answer (score 0):

IF F(X) is odd AND G(x) is even THEN F(x)G(x)=H(x) which is odd F(x)=sina(r(x)) and chose G(x) to be.any.even function eg cosx, x² etc This would make H(x) odd Consider this IF H={ x:x E S(2n+1) for all n E N} Then a possible odd function Z could be constructed z(x)=[f(x)]^(x)

It doesnt matter if f(x) is odd or even so far x satifies the above mentioned set.

DID IT HELP